# Why is my Miller plateau not zero slope (horizontal) but drops down in voltage?

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter

I am a novice in the field and am currently working on a DC-DC converter and was trying to enhance its performance.

After some research, I found out that the Miller plateau is usually of zero slope (so horizontal) but the measurements taken with my oscilloscope exhibit a negative slope.

Instead of stagnating and then increasing again, the voltage drops significantly and then rises again.

What effects make the Miller plateau drop down?

[image: This is the oscillation of the DC-DC converter]

Comment: Emma (Lilly S); you are seeing the battle between two sources of charge, from the gate-drive and from the drain coupled through drain-gate capacitance. For that 0.02 microseconds (20 nanoseconds), the drain voltage is changing very fast and forcing so much charge through the drain-gate capacitance that the gate-drive is over-come. Fortunately the FET remains "on", and you do not have an oscillator.

Comment: Please describe your setup ( half bridge, highside, lowside, voltages and current involved) and also describe your measurement instruments (voltage and current probe brand and model, a photo would also help a lot). There's a high chance your are just seeing some   inducted artifacts

Comment: I agree with @carloc. Without knowing your setup, we cannot give a meaningful answer. I guess what you are seeing could just be the effect of the distributed inductance of the wires/PCB tracks. I't sort of the beginning of a ringing artifact (in which the distributed inductance interacts with the ***nonlinear*** gate capacitance).

Answer (score 2):

Examining the performance, you may need a better GateDriver IC, or a lower inductance IC package, or better Ground/VDD PCB layout to reduce inductance.

Also a Ground Plane may prevent this 'negative slope'.

This region should vary as the input VDD varies, because the slew-rate across drain-gate will vary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPNhrz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>